# Better way to get children using linking objects in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have two Tables, **ProductMapper, Products**. ProductMapper has expiry time of Products.

- A mapper can have multiple products.
- A product can have multiple mappers.
- ProductMapper holds the expiry time of products in it.
- Problem, to find out the `List<Product>` whose `mapper.expiry` is greater than `new Date()` in the given `productIds`

**ProductMapper**

```
import java.util.Date;

import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class ProductMapper extends RealmObject {

    private Date expiry;
    private RealmList<Product> products;

    // Setter, Getter
}
```

**Product**

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.RealmResults;
import io.realm.annotations.LinkingObjects;

public class Product extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean enabled;

    @Nullable
    @LinkingObjects("products")
    private final RealmResults<ProductMapper> mapper = null;
}
```

- The query is broken into multiple parts.
- Get ProductMapper `expiry` greater than current Date.
- Filter out the list of ProductMapper that has the given products `productIds`.
- Now we have all the mapper which are not expired and has atleast one of the given product.
- From this result we get products that are not expired. As ProductMapper can have multiple products, there are chances that, we get products that are not in the `productIds`
- As we are iterating, create query which returns the list of products.
- As ProductMapper can share same products, create a group that are not in the filtered list `productAvail`

Below is the query to find products that are not expired, without duplicates.

```
@NonNull
public static RealmList<Product> getValidProducts(@NonNull long[] productIds) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmQuery<ProductMapper> query = realm.where(ProductMapper.class);
    // Greater than current time.
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("expiry", new Date());

    query.beginGroup();
    for (long productId : productIds) {
        query.equalTo("products.id", productId).or();
    }
    // To bypass "Missing right-hand side of OR" Exception, caused by the above loop
    query.equalTo("products.id", -1);
    query.endGroup();

    RealmList<Product> productAvail = new RealmList<>();
    for (ProductMapper productMapper : query.findAll()) {
        RealmQuery<Product> resQuery = productMapper.getProducts().where();

        // Start Group
        resQuery.beginGroup();
        for (long storeId : productIds) {
            resQuery.equalTo("id", storeId).or();
        }
        // To bypass "Missing right-hand side of OR" Exception, caused by the above loop
        resQuery.equalTo("id", -1);
        // End Group
        resQuery.endGroup();

        // Start Group, this group removes already found products.
        resQuery.beginGroup();
        for (Product product : productAvail) {
            resQuery.notEqualTo("id", product.getId());
        }
        // End Group
        resQuery.endGroup();

        RealmResults<Product> prd = resQuery.findAll();
        productAvail.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(prd));

        // check if we have got all the products. 
        if (productAvail.size() == productIds.length) {
            break;
        }
    }

    realm.close();
    return productAvail;
}
```

Is there a way to find the same with efficient query?

I might end up in getting duplicates, if I search from child to parent & then back to child. As mentioned here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5665#issuecomment-357264095

Comment: `ProductMapper holds the expiry time of products in it.` why doesn't Product hold its own expiry date? In a field like `Date dateExpiry;`?

Comment: ProductMapper has other fields, this is responsible for holding response from server. In runtime it would be inefficient to loop and update expiry date to each item. Until  https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/762 is closed

Comment: ah yes... the bulk update API. Maybe one day...

Answer (score 0):

1.) `ProductMapper` shouldn't even exist. It's just a fancy RealmObject class to make your life miserable, instead of having a `Date` field in `Product`.

2.) In Realm 3.5.0+ your query should be

```
@NonNull
public static RealmResults<Product> getValidProducts(@NonNull Realm realm, @NonNull long[] productIds) {
    return realm.where(Product.class)
                .in("id", productIds)
                .greaterThanOrEqualTo("mapper.expiry", new Date())
                .findAll();
}
```

Comment: I was thinking chaining won't work as mentioned here, https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5665#issuecomment-357264095. I might delete the question if am wrong as this won't be any help to others.

Comment: I think *that* didn't work either because the link was two levels deep, or because he was chaining link queries. That's a bit different.